# Receiver Swaption and Callable Bond - Literature Proof?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, swaption

I'm looking for a formal proof that a receiver swaption is equivalent to a callable bond.

I have only found some CFA Internet pages so far where this statement is considered as proven, tough I haven't seen any papers or books which proof that explicetly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A callable bond can be defined in many ways. You may need to be more specific about the callable bond that you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

A receiver option is definitely not the same thing as a callable bond.  The latter is a security, with an issuer which may default, for one thing.  However, there is a connection, as follows:  a 10yr bond with a coupon of K and a single call option after one year is economically similar to a 10 year non callable bond with a coupon of K minus a 1yr into 9yr receiver swaption struck at K.  Thus, the issuer's option to call the bond is economically similar to a receiver swaption.  This is only an approximation - the issuer's "credit spread" is a factor in valuing callable bonds but it does not affect the value of the receiver swaption.

Comment: I believe that the callable bond referred by OP is a coupon bond with a callable feature.

Comment: I believe the price to call the bond at the call date (corresponding to a coupon payment) SHOULD also be 100% (?) If not then the convertion to a standard receiver swaption may not work(?)

Answer (score 0):

I have reconsidered my previous answer and I think it is possible for any Call price. If the call price ist different from 100% say 102% than one could use a Swaption to receive the fixed coupon and pay a calibrated coupon2 to the corresponding forward Bond price 102%. The calibrated coupon2 would need to be updated at every pricing date.

Comment: [Please merge your accounts](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Also this doesn’t really answer the question, do you have a proof?

Comment: If there is a call premium, this is equivalent to a swaption with an exercise fee, which effectively changes the strike rate of the swaption.

Comment: My last answer "I have reconsidered.....every pricing date." is incorrect. Forget it. Sorry..

Comment: To be precise I was wondering if it is possible to represent/value a european call option on a fix coupon bond (call date on a coupon payment date)  with a strike different from 100%  say 102% using a european receiver swaption. I doubt this is without some kind of adjustment possible...

Answer (score 0):

I have written brief derivation on page 6 of the following document:
https://github.com/phillyfan1138/PaperMarketRisk/blob/master/MarketRiskDocumentation.pdf.  I've implemented a pricing model using the fact that they are equivalent (and unit tested that they are equal) in the following repository: https://github.com/phillyfan1138/HullWhite.  See especially line 392 of HullWhite.h and test "Payer Swaption" in test.cpp.